# JAVA/Selection sort : the console shows different results from what I've entered

Tags: java, selection-sort

I'm learning how to implement `selection sort`.

What I expected from the code is an ascending order output, like: `{1,3,4,5,6,7,9}`

But the console showed: `9, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 7, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1`

What am I supposed to change to get the correct result?

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]arr = {4,6,1,9,5,3,7};
        
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
                if(arr[i]<arr[j]) {
                    int a=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=a;
                   
                
                }
            }
        for (int b = 0; b <arr.length; b++) {
            System.out.print(arr[b] + ", ");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the array while you are doing the sorting. Instead, print the array when you are done with the sorting -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {4, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // first loop
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) { // nested loop
            if (arr[i] < arr[j]) { // if condition
                int a = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = a;
            } // if condition ends
        } // nested loop ends
    } // first loop ends

     // Now the array is sorted, it's good to print.

    for (int b = 0; b < arr.length; b++) {
        System.out.print(arr[b] + ", ");
    }
}
```

There is one more catch. Though your sorting would work, your implementation is not really `selection sort`. It's `bubble sort` implementation. The key difference is, in `selection sort` you need to find the min value and place it in the `ith` position for every `i`. So you only swap once per iteration. In bubble sort, we swap repeatedly like you did.

Also, as pointed out in the comment, for ascending order, you have to flip to condition for swapping. So the correct implementation would be -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {4, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

        int minIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[minIndex] > arr[j]) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
        arr[minIndex] = tmp;
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < arr.length; b++) {
        System.out.print(arr[b] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, the if condition doesn't order in descending order since if i-element < j-element then elements get swapped. I think the check should be inverted, plus in Selection Sort it is not necessary to swap continuosly the elements, you could jut search for the min element of the sub-array and then swap once

Comment: @AndD thanks for your input. I just finished updating my answer and saw that you also notice the incorrect implementation of the selection sort

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way with `Arrays.sort(arr)`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {4,6,1,9,5,3,7};

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selection Sort - java code**

```
  class selectionsort{
    public static void sort(int[] arr){
    int temp,min;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
        min=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
            if(arr[min]>arr[j])
                {
                min=j;
                }
            }
            temp=arr[min];
            arr[min]=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
    int ar[]={4,6,1,9,5,3,7};
    sort(ar);
    System.out.print("After sort :");
      for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
            System.out.print(ar[j]+" ");
      }
    }
  }
```